# How to make a manage a collection of javascript vars, add/remove etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating items which are displayed on a page, I do this with:

```
var popup = "something..."
```

How can I keep a record of all created popup vars and then manage them via:

1. add a new popup var
2. remove a popup var

Any clean ways of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store them in an array, from which you can delete values.

```
var popups = [];

// Add with .push()
popups.push("something");
popups.push("something else");

// Remove with .splice()
// to remove the first element popups[0]
popups.splice(0, 1);

popups.push("third thing");
popups.push("fourth thing");

console.log(popups);
// ["something else", "third thing", "fourth thing"]

// Remove the current second item popups[1]
popups.splice(1,1);

console.log(popups);
// ["something else", "fourth thing"]
```

#### Update

To search and remove a specific element by its value, you can iterate. Recommended: wrap this in a function.

```
for (var i=0; i<popups.length; i++) {
  if (popups[i] === valueToRemove) {
    popups.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Like wrongly how?  I see lots of people here try to use objects like PHP arrays.

Comment: Yea, exactly. All too often :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Didn't recognize your name, so I checked your profile. Did you used to be Tomalak Geret'kal?

Comment: Thanks but that would require me to add and remove items by there added order. Given popups with 5 items, how can I delete a specific item if I have the actual popup var? thx

Comment: @AnApprentice See iterator loop added above.